# How to group by 'key' with associate data listed below appropriate heading

Tags: javascript, grouping, lodash

I am having an issue rendering grouped data with it's associated data.

ex:

''Headding 1''

data 1, data 2, data 3

''Headding 2''

data 1, data 2, data 3

I'm already able to get the 'Headings' but not the corresponding data.  I plan on eventually use vuejs to display the data in a table showing it grouped.

Here's a snippet of the code

```
   for (key in newProgram){
      console.log("HEADING---- "+key+"----")
      for(var x=0; x<newProgram[key]; x++){
        console.log(newProgram[key].company);  //<--- How do I get the corresponding data for each 'HEADING'?
      }
    }
```

Here's the whole [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/OJLpYKG?editors=0012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues.

1. Inner for loop never executed since you have to get the length of the object to loop through.

   newProgram[key].length
2. To get the data you have to use the array index

   newProgram[key][x].company

change the for loop like below

```
for (key in newProgram) {
    console.log("HEADING------ " + key + "----")
    for (var x = 0; x < newProgram[key].length; x++) {
        console.log(newProgram[key][x].company); //<--- How do I get the corresponding data for each 'HEADING'?
    }
}
```